# ERC721 token image not showing in wallet

Tags: solidity, metamask, nft, erc-721

****Hey everyone****

I'm new to NFT development. I developed an ERC-721 token used for property ownership and I deployed and minted a token both on Anvil and sepolia. I can import the token on metamask but its image is not showing up.

please help me know what is the problem and how can i solve it

**the contract on sepolia:** https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x609074096e1f172ced194639c6cf6bca731495d2

**the image IPFS CID:** ipfs://QmVQfqv5YNXL73ypG125BBsooWRiVubF5nm2g9tRtPtyx8

**And the contract code:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import {ERC721} from "@OpenZeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import {Base64} from "@OpenZeppelin/contracts/utils/Base64.sol";
import {Strings} from "@OpenZeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";

contract EProp is ERC721 {
    
    string private s_imageUri;
    address private immutable i_owner;
    uint256 private s_tokenCounter;

    mapping(uint256 => PropSpec) public tokenIdtoSpec;

    struct PropSpec {
        uint256 height;
        uint256 width;
        uint256 x;
        uint256 y;
        //PropType propType;
    }

    constructor(string memory imageUri) ERC721("eProp", "EPR") {
        i_owner = msg.sender;
        s_imageUri = imageUri;
        //s_imageUri:"ipfs://QmVQfqv5YNXL73ypG125BBsooWRiVubF5nm2g9tRtPtyx8"
    }

    function mintProp(
        address propOwner,
        uint256 height,
        uint256 width,
        uint256 x,
        uint256 y
    ) public {
        _safeMint(propOwner, s_tokenCounter);
        PropSpec memory propSpec = PropSpec(height, width, x, y);
        tokenIdtoSpec[s_tokenCounter] = propSpec;
        s_tokenCounter++;
    }

    function _baseURI() internal pure override returns (string memory) {
        return "data:application/json;base64,";
    }

    function tokenURI(
        uint256 tokenId
    ) public view override returns (string memory) {
        string memory height = Strings.toString(tokenIdtoSpec[tokenId].height);
        string memory width = Strings.toString(tokenIdtoSpec[tokenId].width);
        string memory x = Strings.toString(tokenIdtoSpec[tokenId].x);
        string memory y = Strings.toString(tokenIdtoSpec[tokenId].y);
        return
            string(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    _baseURI(),
                    Base64.encode(
                        bytes(
                            abi.encodePacked(
                                '{"name":"',
                                name(),
                                '","description":"EProp is a decentralized property ownership system.","attributes":[{"height":"',
                                height,
                                '","width":"',
                                width,
                                '","x":"',
                                x,
                                '","y":"',
                                y,
                                '"}],"image":"',
                                s_imageUri,
                                '"}'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is from the invalid image URL.
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmVQfqv5YNXL73ypG125BBsooWRiVubF5nm2g9tRtPtyx8

That is the correct format and if you click the link you should see the image clearly.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey there, thanks a lot for the reply,I fixed the contract issue by adding my file to Pinata, the problem was that metamask couldn't get the svg file while my local IPFS node was off and I didn't know that but now it's done